# Page not loading map with api restriction

Tags: javascript, api-key, http-referer, google-developers-console

I'm getting an error "API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError" in my console when I try it render my map.  I put a restriction on HTTP referrers for my website, but it's still not working.  Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: Have you tried googling it? What have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: The current URL loading the Maps JavaScript API has not been added to the list of allowed referrers. Please check the referrer settings of your API key in the Google Cloud Platform Console.

Comment: Ugh, I forgot to add the * after my URL.  Total rookie mistake!